# Rails AssetSync and AWS s3 Bucket Access Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to know why if someone is facing the same problem to get your Rails Assets  files from AWS S3 bucket!

and why keep showing this access denied when i try to get the css upload by AssetSync[image]

Thank you vey much

Comment: You may refer to an answer I gave for [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715747/access-denied-users-permissions-to-s3-bucket/45173606#45173606). Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, objects on S3 are "private" -- they are only accessible if you prove to "own" those objects by providing some credentials in the query string.

To make the objects publicly accessible (ie, without having to sign the requests), you need to attach a policy to the bucket.

To add that permission, go to S3 on the AWS Management Console, click on your bucket, select *Properties*, and there you will see "Permissions". Try that.