# "Access Denied" - User's Permissions to S3 Bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I send out an automated email for orders, and am now trying to have a link to download the a PDF receipt.

User's are getting an error in the browser when trying to download saying **"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."**

[image]

I've gone into the bucket and run "Make Public" on the receipt bucket, still no luck. File structure is:

*app-name/uploads/order/receipt*

***What do I need to do to allow permissions for User's to be able to download their receipts?***

Comment: Have you tried setting the ACL to "public-read" when you upload the object?  You don't mention whether you're using one of the SDKs, or which one, so it's hard to be more specific, but that's how you make an object downloadable by anyone... although, as has been mentioned, signed URLs would be more secure.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I haven't. I'm not sure how (yet) to do that. But, looks like even better, I should look into 'signed URL's', a concept I was unaware of. I'm using CarrierWave and Fog to upload to S3 via a Rails app, not using an SDK.

Comment: Oh, I see the expiration date is a past date, that's the issue. Working on overriding the exp date to allow much more time to download.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a bucket public you should get a new URL that looks like this

http://bucketName.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/order/receipt

... you should use that one in your mail.

But bear in mind that all data is available public, maybe you go better with pre-signed s3 urls that you distrbuted per client.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with a particular file on s3. Solved the issue by changing the access permissions of the file using the mv command and the `--acl` argument. Trying to access a file called `data.jsonlines` gave the `ACCESS DENIED` error. Solved it by running the following commands:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data.jsonlines  s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/gazettes/data_copy.jsonlines 

aws s3 mv --acl public-read s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_copy.jsonlines s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/gazettes/data.jsonlines
```

Or you can **combine** them by running:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_out.jsonlines  s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/gazettes/data_out2.jsonlines && aws s3 mv --acl public-read s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/gazettes/data_out2.jsonlines s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_out.jsonlines
```

These commands carry out the steps below:

- copy: `s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data.jsonlines` to
  `s3://c<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_copy.jsonlines`
- move: `s3://<s3 bucket name>/path/to/file/data_copy.jsonlines` to
  `s3://cfa-opengazettes-ke/path/to/file/data.jsonlines`

Basically, it creates a copy of the file and then deletes it during the move while changing the permissions of the file.

Note the `--acl` option and the argument `public-read`. From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html#options):

> --acl (string) Sets the ACL for the object when the command is performed. If you use this parameter you must have the
>   "s3:PutObjectAcl" permission included in the list of actions for your
>   IAM policy. Only accepts values of **private**, **public-read**,
>   **public-read-write**, **authenticated-read**, **aws-exec-read**,
>   **bucket-owner-read**, **bucket-owner-full-control** and **log-delivery-write**.

Some more useful information at this [AWS page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html)